# Need to flatten a directory, modifying filenames. With bash?

Tags: linux, bash, directory

I have a directory structure with 50,000+ files.  The filenames are of the form `<YYMMDD>-<NNN>.htm`.

The directory structure is

`/<category>/<YYYY>/<MM>/`

For example:

```
./Racing/1998/03/980320-001.htm
./Racing/1998/03/980320-002.htm
...
./General/1999/02/990221-001.htm
./General/1999/02/990221-002.htm
...
```

I want the flat list of files to be of the form

`<category>-<YYYY>-<MM>-<DD>-<NNN>`

So the above would be

```
Racing-1998-03-20-001.htm
Racing-1998-03-20-002.htm
...
General-1999-02-21-001.htm
General-1999-02-21-002.htm
```

I'm (re)learning bash & regex and would appreciate some pointers on how to implement this.

I know how to generate the list of paths, but not how to apply a regex to convert the form.  I would use `find -type f -name "*.htm" | <some goblygook here>`

where `<some goblygook here>` might utilize `xargs`...

Thanks in advance.

**[EDIT 3/30 9:58pm]**

Per the answers below I've concocted this script. I cannot get `xargs` to work:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir ./flat
find -type f -name "*.htm" | \
awk -F'[/]' '
BEGIN{OFS="-"}
{ gsub(/^\.\//,"") ;print "./" $0 " ./flat/" $1,$2, substr($4,3,2),substr($4,5,2),substr($4,8)}
' | \
xargs -p -d "\n" -n 1 cp
```

Running this gives me:

```
$ ./awktest.sh
mkdir: cannot create directory `./flat': File exists
cp ./General/1997/05/970525-002.htm ./flat/General-1997-05-25-002.htm ?...y
cp: missing destination file operand after `./General/1997/05/970525-002.htm ./flat/General-1997-05-25-002.htm'
Try `cp --help' for more information.
^C
```

Copying the exact `cp` command (`cp ./General/1997/05/970525-002.htm ./flat/General-1997-05-25-002.htm`) from that output and pasting it directly into the bash prompt works fine.

I tried figuring out how to use `-print0` on the `find` command but could not figure out how to get `awk` to use `\0` as the record terminator (`RS="\0"` would not work).  I think the problem has to do with newlines, but I'm at a loss!

Comment: It's worth pointing out that there was a good reason why the directory structure was like that, and not flat - if you end up with too many files in one directory, many filesystems perform badly and the directory becomes unwieldy to work with using standard tools.

Comment: @caf - thanks.  I'm actually doing this as a test of Amazon S3 where I _want_ there to be this many files in my bucket.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is usually no need to use `sed` when `awk` is present. This is another answer that doesn't fork extra `sed` process

```
find -type f -name "*.htm" | awk -F'[/]' 'BEGIN{OFS="-"}{ gsub(/^\.\//,"") ;print $1,$2, substr($4,3,2),substr($4,5,2),substr($4,8) }'
```

Edit, you can do your `cp` inside `awk`

```
find -type f -name "*.htm" | awk -F'[/]' 'BEGIN{OFS="-"}{ 
   gsub(/^\.\//,"") 
   source = $1 OFS $2 OFS substr($4,3,2) OFS substr($4,5,2) OFS substr($4,8) 
   destination = <create your destination here>
   command = "cp "source" "destination
   system(command)
}'
```

Comment: this works too. I like the fact that it only involves one tool. If I understand this correctly, -F'[/]' tells awk the delimter is / and OFS="-" says "when outputting perameters put a - between them". Right?

Comment: @tig, yes. and no, it involves 2 tools (find +awk) :). If you have bash 4 and above, you can do it with just bash and no external tools. :)

Comment: I meant 1 tool in addition to find.

Comment: & @James.Xu - can you look at my edit above and help me? thanks.

Comment: Excellent!  You kinda had source/dest backwards and $0 works for source but it works now. But I'd love to understand WHY xargs didn't work in the above...

Answer (score 3):

`find -type f -name "*.htm" | sed 's@^./@@g;s@/@-@g' | awk -F'-' '{print $1 "-" $2 "-" $3 "-" substr($4, 5, 2) "-" $5}'`

[sed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed) & [awk](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Awk) are very useful for text manipulation.

Comment: This is flipping awesome. It works. Blows me away you didn't need to test it. Anyway, I want to understand it, so I hope you won't mind answering some more questions.  First, I can't find docs on what the @ do in the sed command; what's going on there?

Comment: you might see some sed command like: sed 's/aaa/bbb/g' where '/' is used to seperate the strings. but when you have '/' in your string, you need to use some other character, here i used '@', it could be any other charater.

Comment: Note the "dot" in "./" need to be escaped . `@^\./@`

Comment: @James.Xu - My sed knowledge from college is now restored. ; indicates another sed command. So the two commands are "replace all instances of ./ with nothing" and "replace all instances of / with -" Cool (although the first g is not needed).

Comment: @kurumi - perhaps technically, but it appears to work as is.  Why do you say this?

Comment: @tig, yeah sure, it works for your case where all the data starts with dot slash. Technically, `^./` says to match ANY character from the start followed by `/`, not just a dot. So strings like `A/path1/path2` will get substituted.

Answer (score 2):

I had to adjust the accepted answer to work for me:

```
find -type f -name "*.png" | awk -F'[/]' 'BEGIN{OFS="_"}{ 
   gsub(/^\.\//,"") 
   source = "source root folder" $1 "/" $2 "/" $3 
   destination = "destination folder" $1 OFS $2 OFS $3
   command = "cp "source" "destination
   system(command)
}'
```

Answer (score -1):

To copy your files as such:

```
eval "`find -type f -name "*.htm" |awk -F/ '{print "cp " $0 " " $2 "-" $3 "-" $4 "-" substr($5,5) ";" }'`"
```

Comment: don't use `eval` unnecessarily

Comment: @kurumi we should just get rid of the `eval` command completely.  Got it.  This isn't production code with injection risk.